# Disable calendar pages

Tags: middleman

For the gem 'middleman-blog' is there a way to disable the generation of calendar pages?

Is there also an option to target the disabling of specific calendar pages, such as month and day pages?

I've tried looking at the source on Github, but there is no indication of such a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When on middleman local/preview server (`middleman server`), look up the settings in your middleman configuration at `<host>/__middleman/config`. In there check for the `:calendar_template` setting under configurations for `:blog`, if it's not `nil` then set it to `nil` in your `config.rb`. It's similar for day, month and yearly pages.

Example :

```
// File : config.rb
activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.current_template = nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this gives me an error on build. Using --verbose I see the the calendar is still being built with the following error: `undefined local variable or method `page_type' for #<Middleman::Application:0x70297551299920>`.

Comment: Do you have a `calendar.html.erb` file in your source ?

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks for the assist!